# Is there any way to search for something below a certain value inside a couple arrays?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I have the following JSON:

```
{
"hominis": [20000, "asd"],
"omint": [30000, "asd"]
}
```

and I would like to make a function that returns all array names (hominis, omint) whose **arr[0]** value is under my **input value**

e.g:

```
if (myInput <= arr[0]) {
return arrName
}
```

I would like to go through my arrays (hominis, omint) and return their **names** if the condition is matched. I believe it has something to do with **for** loops, but I couldn't do it.
I've started JS two weeks ago so I'm a newbie.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys of an object like following snippet,

```
var a = {
    "hominis": [20000, "asd"],
    "omint": [30000, "asd"]
};

var minValue = 25000;
var keys = Object.keys(a); // Returns all keys in the object

for (let key of keys) { // Loop over all the keys
    if (a[key][0] > minValue) { // Check if value at key matches your condition
        console.log(key); // return/add to your new array/ or whatever to the matching key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not say how to show your output. I am assuming it will be array of names.

```js
let data = {
  hominis: [20000, "asd"],
  omint: [30000, "asd"],
};
myInput = 20001;
let x = Object.entries(data).reduce((p, [x, y]) => {
  if (myInput <= y[0]) p.push(x);
  return p;
}, []);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "for in obj".

```js
var obj1 = {
    "hominis": [20000, "asd"],
    "omint": [30000, "asd"]
}

function findMinorThan(obj, limit) {
    let res = []
    for (const k in obj) {
        if (obj[k][0] < limit) {
            res.push(k)
        }
    }
    return res
}
console.log(findMinorThan(obj1, 25000));
```